# Laravel (5.8) observer deleted is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, observers

I am using Laravel (5.8) and I need to delete a record from table A and then also table B.
So I tried Observers, but it never fired the observer's `deleted`  method.

I already used other methods like `updating` or `updated`, so I don't know why the `deleted` method is not firing.
I don't use soft delete, because I didn't make this database schema and I don't have authorities to modify that. But based on what I read from the document, it doesn't matter..right?

Here are my code.

- Pay Controller.php

```
public function delete(Request $request, $idx){
    $payData = PaymentData::where('idx', $idx)->delete();
    return response()->json(['status' => true]);
}
```

- PayObserver.php

```
public function deleted(PaymentData $paymentData)
{
        if ($paymentData->pay_type == "PA") {
            $app = AppData::where('oid', $paymentData->oid)->first();

            if (!empty($app)) {
                $app->delete();
            }
        }
}
```

- AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    \App\Models\PaymentData::observe(\App\Observers\PayObserver::class);
}
```

I also tried to add the observe statement to boot method in `EventServiceProvider.php`, but it wasn't working either.
I read the official document but couldn't find any clues..what did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

found it.

Instead of doing this,

```
$payData = PaymentData::where('idx', $idx)->delete();
```

I should have done like this.

```
$payData = PaymentData::where('idx', $idx)->first();
$payData->delete();
```

I thought I already tried this...
Anyway, that's it. Hope the Officail documents have more details. :)

Comment: Looks like observers only fire when operating on a model, not when operating on a builder

Comment: @chiliNUT yes, I had this issue on laravel 8, idk about version 9 and 10.

Comment: The official page has the example code like the first one as "Deleting Models By Query", and then they said "When executing a mass delete statement via Eloquent, the deleting and deleted model events will not be fired for the deleted models. " in [HERE](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#deleting-models).
So I thought I was doing the right way, but it wasn't.